# MS SQL Server - Query containing several joins displayes correct amount of entries, combined with OR conditions, I get lots of duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I got this query at the end of it Im looking for a certain value which can be 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6, when I look for any of these values without the others e.g. only 2 I get the correct amount of rows, but as soon as i combine them with "OR" statements I get a huge list containing duplicates.

```
select 
bkm.tblProject.sCode ,bkm.tblPart.sPart ,
bkm.tblPart.dReturnOrder , bkm.tblUser.sMail , bkm.tblPart.BuildStart  ,
bkm.tblPart.BuildEnd ,ret.tblInvoice.TargetDate ,ret.tblInvoice.dInvoice ,
ret.tblInvoice.PaymentDate ,ret.tblInvoice.dPayment ,ret.tblInvoice.sName ,
bkm.tblPart.nProjectId, ret.tblInvoice.nProjectId

from bkm.tblPart

left join bkm.tblUser on 
bkm.tblPart.nManagerId =bkm.tblUser.nUserId 


left join bkm.tblProject on  
bkm.tblPart.nProjectId=bkm.tblProject.nProjectId


inner join ret.tblInvoice on 
bkm.tblPart.nProjectId =ret.tblInvoice.nProjectId


left join bkm.tblScopeState on 
ret.tblInvoice.nStatusId =  bkm.tblScopeState.nKeyId


left join bkm.tblInvoiceType on 
ret.tblInvoice.nProjectId=bkm.tblInvoiceType.nProjectId

where  ret.tblInvoice.nTypeId = bkm.tblInvoiceType.nKeyId 
and not bkm.tblPart.dReturnOrder=0
and bkm.tblScopeState.nScopeId=205 and bkm.tblScopeState.nMandantId=4
and ret.tblInvoice.nProjectId=bkm.tblInvoiceType.nProjectId
and bkm.tblPart.nStatusId=3
```

as soon as i change the last line to

```
and bkm.tblPart.nStatusId=3 or bkm.tblPart.nStatusId=2
```

I get a huge list full of duplicates, but when I check them one by one without the "OR" statement everything looks right.
Im not sure what to look for, first I thought that I'm using wrong "JOIN" statements but then I would get wrong results even when checking for only one `bkm.tblPart.nStatusId`.

Comment: maybe try `and (bkm.tblPart.nStatusId=3 or bkm.tblPart.nStatusId=2)`

Comment: More light reading on operator precedence: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Two words: *USE PARENTHESIS*.

Comment: ANDs and ORs have the same precedence, so if you write WHERE clauses that mix the two, the parser has no idea that you want the ORs executed before the ANDs and it just does them in the order they are written. If you want the ORs executed first, then you have to tell the compiler that by using parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't put the OR condition in parenthesis like suggested in the comment made by Stu you are effectively specifying

```
where  ret.tblInvoice.nTypeId = bkm.tblInvoiceType.nKeyId 
and not bkm.tblPart.dReturnOrder=0
and bkm.tblScopeState.nScopeId=205 and bkm.tblScopeState.nMandantId=4
and ret.tblInvoice.nProjectId=bkm.tblInvoiceType.nProjectId
and bkm.tblPart.nStatusId=3
```

OR

```
nStatusId = 2
```

There is a big chance of duplication when you leave out the first condition `ret.tblInvoice.nTypeId = bkm.tblInvoiceType.nKeyId`

Comment: FYI, the term in English is *parentheses* `(..)`, brackets `[..]` and braces `{..}` are used for other things in SQL.